# I would like to use the IranNastaliq font with xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, languages

I would like to use the IranNastaliq font with xelatex, the document below throws an error when I try to compile it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\defpersianfont\Nastaliq{IranNastaliq}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Nastaliq}{\N@stliq}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Nastaliq}

این طرح‌نما می‌آزماید نگاره و اندازه و شکل را

\end{Nastaliq}
\end{document}
```

### Error

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "IranNastaliq" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.6 

? 

Package fontspec Warning: Font "IranNastaliq" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Persian".


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "IranNastaliq/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "IranNastaliq/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "IranNastaliq/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


! Package fontspec Error: The font "IranNastaliq" cannot be found.
```

Comment: try if it works if you use the file name.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, the filename of the font instead of the font name?

Comment: yes exactly. finding the right font name is a bit tricky with xelatex (and font names don't work for all locations).

Comment: Ok, this implies I should have downloaded the font before I tried this example. I didn't. Seems like I should first find the font then.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to define an environment.
Use the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\defpersianfont\nas[Scale=4]{IranNastaliq}
\begin{document}
\begin{nas}
این طرح‌نما می‌آزماید نگاره و اندازه و شکل را
\end{nas}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Of course, you must first make sure your font is installed.
If you are a `Windows 10` user, right-click on the font and select
`Install for all users`. If you install it only for your own user account, Windows will put a copy in a hidden directory that XeTeX does not search (and you will need to remove it in the Fonts control panel if you ever want to install it for all users).

On Mac, you would want to install it to the System Font Book.  On Linux, there are several places to put it, including `/usr/local/share/fonts/` to install it for everyone, and `~/.fonts/` to install it just for yourself.

If you only want to use the font for TeX, and not have it available in your other apps, you can instead put it in a subdirectory of your local TeX tree.  Which directory that is will vary, but you can normally find it with

```
kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
```

On the Windows version of TeX Live, for example, this will typically be `C:\texlive\texmf-local\`.  On MikTeX, you might need to create a local TeX tree in the MikTeX console.  The conventional place to put the file would be under `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\opentype\IranNastaliq\`, where you probably need to create the sub=folders yourself, but that’s just to make it easier for you to find and delete them later.  Dropping the files anywhere in the tree is all the same to XeTeX.

If you’re on a shared computer and don’t have permission to change the TeX installation, you can use the `TEXMFHOME` directory instead of `TEXMFLOCAL`.  The command to find that is

```
kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

If you only need the font for one project, or if you want to make sure you archive one particular version of the font with your project, you can save a copy in your project directory, and XeTeX should find it.

Wherever you put the font, you then might want to update the TeX font caches.  (This step is optional.)  To do so, run as an administrator either a powershell or a command prompt (hit Win-X on Windows) and run `fc-cache.exe -f -s -v`.  If you also use LuaLaTeX, you might additionally want to run `luaotflaod-tool -f -u -p -v`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am a spoiled user of the latin alphabet with latex. I was always happy with Computer Modern fonts. That's why I just assumed that the default set of latex fonts contain iranian-nastaliq font and I can just specify it and use it. I primarily use **GNU/Linux** and sometimes **macos**. I have yet to discover a reliable source of high-quality iranian fonts, preferably open and free (free as in freedom) fonts. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: Actually it depends on which fonts you prefer.i recommend Yas or XB Niloofar.

Comment: well, I am explicitly looking for nastaligh. xb-niloofar looks good for print though. Do you know a good and reliable site to obtain nastaligh?

Comment: This got bumped back to the main page, so I updated it. It now tells you how to find your local TeX tree, instead of giving the default location of the system tree on one distribution.